# MATLAB slice functionality without using meshgrid

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D big matrix of size 2001 , 2001 , 30. I want to show its 30 slices in a 3D plot. I try to do it using matlab 'slice' command. However, since 'slice' needs to get the X Y Z locations as 3D arrays from the 'meshgrid' command, I get an 'out of memory error'.

My code is presented below.

How can I get over the 'Out of Memory' error without having to shrink 
my 3D matrix, and with using my x,y,z locations of the matrix data ??

```
function  presentFig4_ver4

close all; clc; 

%im3 is of size of  im3 = 201  201  30
load('img3D_shrinked.mat' , 'im3' , 'y_n_mm' , 'x_n_mm')

% next code until the mesh grid  is in order to have the axes arranged
% so that the slices are shown one after the other in the depth
% direction of the figure and not from the bottom of the figure to the top of the figure  
x_len=length(x_n_mm);
y_len=length(y_n_mm);

im3_reshaped=zeros(y_len , x_len , y_len);

for (ind_slice=1:30)
    im3_reshaped(:,ind_slice,:)=im3(:,:,ind_slice);
end

[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(x_n_mm,y_n_mm,y_n_mm);        

slices=x_n_mm %= 0.23:0.1:(0.23+((30-1)*0.1));  %This is the same as x_n_mm 
shownSlices=[1:30];

h=slice(X,Y,Z, im3_reshaped, [slices(shownSlices)],[],[]);
set(h,'EdgeColor','none','FaceColor','interp');
set(  h , 'FaceAlpha',  'interp','AlphaData',im3*10^3)       

dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf); %datacursor mode on
set(dcm_obj,'enable','on','updatefcn',{@updateMe X Y Z im3_reshaped}) %update, need X,Y,Z, im3-values

set(gca,'FontName', 'Arial' ,'FontSize',14)

set(gca,'Position',[.32 .19 .41  0.9])   % [horizontal distance, vertical distance, width, height]

hold on

%camproj perspective
c_h=colorbar('horiz');
set( c_h, 'XDir', 'reverse' , 'Position' , [0.2 0.2 0.7 0.04],'FontSize',12);
opengl software
daspect([ 1 10 10])

axis tight

view(-49,16)

maxAxisLim=2;  %mm

ylim([-maxAxisLim maxAxisLim])
zlim([-maxAxisLim maxAxisLim])
xlim([0.23 3.13])
camzoom(2)
xlabel('X [mm]','FontName', 'Arial' , 'FontSize',14)
ylabel('Y[mm]','FontName', 'Arial' ,'FontSize',14)
zlabel('Z [mm]','FontName', 'Arial' , 'FontSize',14)
x_h=get(gca,'XLabel');
y_h=get(gca,'YLabel');
z_h=get(gca,'ZLabel');

set(y_h, 'Units','normalized','Position', [0.03 -0.08 ] );
set(x_h, 'Units','normalized','Position', [0.6 0.12] );
set(z_h, 'Units','normalized','Position', [-0.08 0.27] );


set(get(gca,'YLabel'),'Rotation',-20);
set(get(gca,'XLabel'),'Rotation',12);

set(gca,'XTick',[0.23 0.5:0.5:3 3.13])
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0.23' '0.5' '1' '1.5' '2' '2.5' '3' '3.1' })

end  % of presentFig4_ver4 function

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

function msg = updateMe(src,evt,X,Y,Z,f)
    evt = get(evt); %what's happenin'?
    pos = evt.Position; %position
    fval = f(X==pos(1)&Y==pos(2)&Z==pos(3)); %where?
    msg = num2str(fval); %create msg  
end
```

Comment: Do you just want to be able to scroll through the different slices? In that case, you can maybe use the [imshow3Dfull-script](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/47463-imshow3dfull--3d-imshow-in-3-views-)

Comment: No. I want to present the data in a nice 3D figure.

Comment: You mean rendering it in 3D? I'm not an expert, but maybe you can try the `isosurface` and `patch` commands